# Meteor / Iron Router Prevent iFrame re-render

Tags: javascript, iframe, meteor, iron-router, meteor-blaze

I'm trying to use Meteor / Iron Router to make a pretty simple app with 2-3 pages with one of the pages requiring an iframe to embed the contents.

The embedded content, http://trycelery.com, is added quite similarly to Facebook Comments, a div with data attributes and a JS initialization. When navigating away from the page and back to the route with the embedded content, the page is rerendered and doesn't fire properly the second time around. I would imagine this is because I ahve it sitting inside of {{> yield}} so it is to be expected.

I've tried a couple things I've seen scatered across Stack like:

- using pathFor link instead of the actual absolute path
- I found "constant"'s which might have been promising but is no longer available
- tried to get something hacky to work with Template.TemplateName.rendered but couldn't figure anything out

Any solution aside from keeping it outside of the {{>yield}} and just show/hiding it with navigation?

Edit: Currently showing/hiding it with CSS with the following but would prefer to move it into the template if possible.

```
<div id="thepage" class="{{isPage}}">
Template.AppLayout.helpers({
    isPage: function() {
        if ( Router.current().route.getName() == 'thepage' ) {
            return 'is-active';
        } else {
            return 'not-active';
    }
});
```